# Camel FOP and userConfigURL directory

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I have a fop.xconf that sets the baseUrl.

On Jetty, it works by doing the following:

```
.to("fop:application/pdf?userConfigURL=../<web-module>/src/main/resources/fop.xconf")
```

It will not work on Tomcat given that "src/main/resources" does not exist.

I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to run on both Jetty and Tomcat.

Comment: Have you tried with userConfigurURL=classpath:fop.xcon

Comment: Or just plain userConfiugURL=fop.xcon. Assuming it would load from the classpath by default.

Comment: Confirmed.  v2.11 does not load from classpath by prefixing url with "classpath:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camel-fop cannot currently load the user config from classpath. So I have logged a ticket to implement this in the upcoming 2.12 release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6666

Comment: Thanks!  Will grab snapshot and try it out.